# Inserting a string between certain characters in another string

Tags: java

Say I have a string, say `String stringy = "<Monkey><Banana><Raffle/>"`

and another string `String stringier = <Cool stuff to add/>`

How can I insert `stringier` between the closing `>` of `<Banana>` and the opening `<` of `<Raffle/>`? I can't use the index of the string either, because `stringy` could have more or less characters before the `<Raffle/>` and will likely never be the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this xml or is it your custom markup language syntax?

Comment: If this is actually XML ( it's syntactically incorrect at the moment BTW ) then you might want to treat it as XML rather than just as strings. Java has rich support for XML. It may be overkill for a simple use case such as this, but if your application is full of such statements it might be worth investing the time in learning on the XML API's

Comment: @DaveHowes it is xml, but the above is just a (poor) simplification of what I was trying to do. I'll look into the API's, but screenmutt's answer will certainly do for now.

Comment: jdom is my favourite XML API - much easier than the standard API that ships with java ( www.jdom.org )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just looking for a find and replace? If not, can you expand on your question?

```
stringy = stringy.replace("<Banana><Raffle/>", "<Banana>"+ stringier +"<Raffle/>")
```

Comment: the thing is, <Raffle/> will always be the same. But whatever is before <Raffle/>, in this case <Banana>, might sometimes be <Oranges> or <Quesadillas>, <etc>...

would the replaceAll still work if it was `stringy.replaceAll("><Raffle/>",">" + stringier "<Raffle/>")`?

Comment: Yes. That would work. You might look into learning [Regex](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) which might be helpful if you get into advanced find and replace. I seriously have dreams about marrying regex I love them so much.

Comment: I'm familiar with them but am not an expert by any means, I'll look into them a bit more though. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This can be another option:

```
stringy = stringy.substring(0, stringy.indexOf("<Banana>") + "<Banana>".length()) 
      + stringier 
      + stringy.substring(stringy.indexOf("<Banana>") + "<Banana>".length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.indexOf to find an occurrence of a string within another string. So, maybe it would look something like this.

```
    String stringy = "<Monkey><Banana><Raffle/>";
    String stringier = "<Cool stuff to add/>";

    String placeToAdd = "<Banana><Raffle/>";
    String addAfter = "<Banana>";
    int temp;

    temp = stringy.indexOf(placeToAdd);
    if(temp != -1){
        temp = temp+addAfter.length();

        stringy = stringy.substring(0, temp) + stringier + stringy.substring(temp+1, stringy.length());

        System.out.println(stringy);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Stringier \'" + stringier+"\" not found");
    }
```

After looking at other answers, replace is probably a better option than the substring stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Java strings are immutable, but StringBuilder is not.

```
public class StringyThingy {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder stringy = new StringBuilder("<Monkey><Banana><Raffle/>");

    System.out.println(stringy);

    // there has to be a more elegant way to find the index, but I'm busy.
    stringy.insert(stringy.indexOf("Banana")+"Banana".length()+1,"<Cool stuff to add/>");

    System.out.println(stringy);
  }
}

// output
<Monkey><Banana><Raffle/>
<Monkey><Banana><Cool stuff to add/><Raffle/>
```